# scipy root return guess if function undefined

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to make a parameter study. I have a very complex function which is not define for all values.

I make parameter variation and any time take roots but if the parameter make my function undefined then `scipy.optimize.root()`  return the guess value instead of an error or `'nan'`.

How can I get root only if the function is defined (without having to determine first the space where my function is defined)?

I tried to create a simple example to facilitate understanding:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

global k
def F(X):
    np.seterr(all='raise')
    try:
       f1=np.log(4.80-(X+k))
       return f1
    except:
       return np.nan

guess = 10
ks=[i/2.0 for i in range(10)]
for k in ks: 
    root(F, guess)
```

Comment: "if the function is defined (without having to determine first the space where my function is defined)": I don't think you can do actually that.

Comment: @9769953 I have try to use `try / except`. (See edit in my post) but it didn't solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the try-except block around the root function; that is also where you want to test for nan. You should further catch the specific exception that scipy/root is raising, not every exception.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def myroot(F, guess):
    np.seterr(all='raise')
    try:
        res = root(F, guess)
    except FloatingPointError as exp:
        return guess
    if np.isnan(res):
        return guess
    return res

global k
def F(X):
    return np.log(4.80-(X+k))

ks=[i/2.0 for i in range(10)]
guess = 10
for k in ks:
    print(myroot(F, guess))
```

Comment: this does not work because `try: res=root(F, guess)`  never return warning or error. If `F` not define at this point it return the value of `guess`

Comment: @Dadep Of course `root` raises an exception for invalid calculations, so it does work. And if `F` is not defined, another exception than the floating point error will be raised; nothing will be returned.